# Related to model( each song need each artist)

Tags: python, django

I have created this model. But I need `each song need each artist` How Is it possible? 
I have no idea. Here is my [model  screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrslR.jpg) Can you please help me ? thank you

```
class Song(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,help_text="Album Name")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True,help_text="Must be unique.")
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_6 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #
    type = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

UPDATE2: Thank guys. I think its not right solution. If I have to found `song_5` is belong to `this album` and to this `artist`. How is it possible? :-?

```
    class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    song_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_5 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    song_6 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    album = models.ManyToManyField(Album)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Your database model looks awful. Why not split artists, albums and songs into different tables? Or, if you don't want/need that for some reason (e.g. if your models represent actual mp3 files), at least use a table with artist/album/songtitle fields instead of this horrible mess with multiple songs in the same row.

Comment: @ThiefMaster You are right. Will you post your answer? So I can choose. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best Solution is `InlineModel`. Here is link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin
Thanks anyways. Here is [my output](http://i.imgur.com/M9319.jpg)

Here is My model

```
    class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

here is admin.py

```
class SongInline(admin.TabularInline):
    #list_display = ('title','artist','song_1','song_2','song_3','song_4','song_5','song_6')
    #prepopulated_fields = { 'slug': ['title'] }
    model = Song

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
            SongInline,
            ]
class ArtistAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `Song` class, add a field:

```
artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
```

Then each song will have only one artist, but the artists can have many songs. If you want a song to have many artists, use `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: I have applied ManyToManyField `artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)`. But How to make relation with album?

Comment: @no_freedom The same way, but let the `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` point to the `Album` class, and in the `Album` class add a field pointing to the artist as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create relations between artists, songs and albums.

In your case a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) ist probably sufficient, but as 
this is really a broad and fundamental topic you should definitely read the docs on [`Relationships`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#relationships).